# How to convert jar file into apk?

Tags: java, android, jar, apk

I have one jar file, when I clicked that jar file, it was opened one window based application.

Now I would like to convert this jar file into apk file. 
That jar file having 5 class files. 
How can I know the initial class file? and 
How could I code on this in android?

Please do the needful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download/PeaZip_64_bit_72908_p/) may be useful for you

Comment: @lavanya are you asking here to  convert a swing based app to a android app ??

Answer (score 1):

> How can I know the initial class file?

Please read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html .You should have a look at following part:

> If you have an application bundled in a JAR file, you need some way to
>   indicate which class within the JAR file is your application's entry
>   point. You provide this information with the Main-Class header in the
>   manifest, which has the general form:.......

Answering to your next question:

> How could I code on this in android?

Import JAR file to Android Project. You can get JAR's entry point from Manifest file ( not AndroidManiefst.xml but from JAR's Manifest). However, you mentioned:

> it was opened one window based application.

It looks like those 5 classes have dependencies on some different JARs which could not be available on Android platform.

Comment: Thank you. I found the entry point from jar file. Now how could I call this entry point from my android app?
The jar file my client used swing. Is it possible to show the same screen to my android app?

Comment: You can use one of Swing implementations for Android like: http://www.creamtec.com/services/index.html or if it's just 5 classes it should be easy to rewrite UI layer on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert J2ME apps (jar/jad) to Android (apk) using UpOnTek's conversion services. Service includes automatic conversion, followed by optimization tips.